# WPF Почему контекстное меню не видит свойство зависимости пользовательского элемента?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, usercontrol, popupmenu

Доброго времени суток всем!

Код привожу ниже. Проблема в следующем. Есть пользовательский элемент (`ModuleFrameView`), состоящий из нескольких textbox'ов. Этот же `ModuleFrameView` имеет свойство зависимости `ItemSource` типа `Module`. Данный тип `Module` состоит в свою очередь из нескольких свойств, к которым привязаны текстбоксы. Наконец, несколько пользовательских элементов `ModuleFrameView` составляют содержание другого пользовательского элемента `HomeScreenView`, из модели представления которого я и управляю всем содержимым.

Все работает, все всех видят, за исключением одного: контекстное меню на текстбоксах не видит `ItemSource` и соответственно свойства класса `Module`. Знаю, что контекстное меню находится в другом дереве, пробовал переопределять `DataContext` с помощью `PlacementTarget`. Ничего не помогает. Видимо, что-то делаю не так, а что - не могу понять. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с описанной выше проблемой? (В ниже приведенном коде есть некоторые синтаксические особенности из-за использования мною Caliburn.Micro. Но надеюсь, это не мешает пониманию сути вопроса.)

mUserControl UserControl xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.Views.ModuleFrameView" x:Name="mUserControl">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox
            x:Name="txt5"
            Text="{Binding ItemSource.Ch1SET, ElementName=mUserControl}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding ItemSource.IsEnbl_5, ElementName=mUserControl}"
            IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Center"
            ContextMenuService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
            Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                          AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
            <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Name="cm">
                    <MenuItem
                        Header="Enable" cal:Message.Attach="cmEnable($source)"
                        IsCheckable="True"
                        IsChecked="{Binding
                            Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.ItemSource.IsEnbl_5,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                            AncestorType=TextBox}}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBox.ContextMenu>
            <!--...-->
```

`ModuleFrameView` определяет свое зависимости `ItemSource` в своем code-behind файле:

```
public Module ItemSource
{
    get { return (Module)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSource", typeof(Module), typeof(ModuleFrameView),
                                new PropertyMetadata(default(Module)));
```

Свойство зависимости ItemSource типа Module:

```
public class Module : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _ch1SET;
    public string Ch1SET
    {
        get { return _ch1SET; }
        set
        {
            if (_ch1SET == value) return;
            _ch1SET = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Ch1SET);
        }
    }

    private bool _isEnbl_5;
    public bool IsEnbl_5
    {
        get { return _isEnbl_5; }
        set
        {
            if (_isEnbl_5 == value) return;
            _isEnbl_5 = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsEnbl_5);
        }
    }

    //...
    //...lot of properties
```

Второй пользовательский элемент-контейнер `HomeScreenView`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.Views.HomeScreenView">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl>
            <loc:ModuleFrameView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                                 ItemSource="{Binding ModuleArr[0]}"/>
            <loc:ModuleFrameView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                 ItemSource="{Binding ModuleArr[1]}"/>
            <!--...-->
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка:

```
IsChecked="{Binding
    Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.ItemSource.IsEnbl_5,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                    AncestorType=TextBox}}"/>
```

Дело в том, что `RelativeSource` будет идти вверх только до конца визуального дерева, упрётся в `Popup`, и никогда не попадёт в `TextBox`. Да и `PlacementTarget` — свойство контекстного меню.

Вы имели в виду, судя по всему, `AncestorType=ContextMenu`?

В этом случае `PlacementTarget` — это `TextBox`. `Tag` — `UserControl`, и `ItemsSource` приходит из его `DataContext`'а.